# passing null value from az cli to bash without exiting

Tags: bash, syntax, azure-cli, io-redirection, command-substitution

I'm trying to get the value of a resource in azure via AZ CLI, and pass that value to a variable in bash.

```
id=$(az synapse workspace show -n $name -g $rsname --query 'identity.principalId' -o tsv 2<&1)
if [[ $id == *"Not Found"* ]];
then
    echo "Workspace already deleted."
fi
```

If the resource is not there, I am redirecting the output to the variable with 2<&1 so I can deal with it in the if-then conditional.  $id is getting assigned the output correctly, but AZ CLI is still exiting the script with error "not found".

Is there anyway to keep it from exiting?

Comment: Add output of your `az` command to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Replace `<` with `>` to redirect stderr (2) to stdout (1)?

Answer (score 0):

In your bash command you are using **2<&1** that's why it ***exited the script with error "not found"***

You can achieve this by using "**2>&-**".

> Make sure you have to use the Greater than (**>**) symbol.

```
    id=$(az synapse workspace show -n '<synapse Name>' -g '<Resource Group Name>' --query 'identity.principalId' -o tsv 2>&-)
```

#### using "2>&-":

I can be able to **get the principal id**.
[image]

#### using "2>&1":

here I am **not able** to get the **principal id**.
[image]

#### Reference

- [using bash check the program is exist or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/15997690)
- [Usage of bash IO Redirection](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)